# Picking from lists depending on other lists

Tags: python

I am trying to make a thing that picks a class and a build for my next character in a game. I can get it to pick the class, but I can't figure out why it wont pick the build. I am still really new so this probably isn't the cleanest or easiest way to do this.

```
import random

Classes=["Demon                 Hunter","Monk","Crusader","Barbarian","Necromancer","Wizard","Witch Doctor"]

DHBuild=["Impale","Multishot","Natalya's"]
MBuild=["Wave of Light","Uliana's EP","Sunwuko LTK",]
CBuild=["Condemn","Blessed Shield","Sweep Attack"]
BRBuild=["Hammer of the Ancients","WhirlWind","LeapQuake"]
NECROBuild=["Pestilance","Rathma Mages","Inarius"]
WIZBuild=["Frozen Orb","Lightning Hydra","TalVyrs Archon"]
WDBuild=["Arachyr FireBats","Jade Harvester","Helltooth FireBats"]

picked=print(random.choice(Classes))

print(picked)

if picked=="Demon Hunter":
    PickedBuild=print(random.choice(DHBuild))
    print(PickedBuild)

if picked=="Monk":
    PickedBuild=print(random.choice(MBuild))
    print(PickedBuild)

if picked=="Crusader":
    PickedBuild=print(random.choice(CBuild))
    print(PickedBuild)

if picked=="Barbarian":
    PickedBuild=print(random.choice(BRBuild))
    print(PickedBuild)

if picked=="Necromancer":
    PickedBuild=print(random.choice(NECROBuild))
    print(PickedBuild)

if picked=="Wizard":
    PickedBuild=print(random.choice(WIZBuild))
    print(PickedBuild)

if picked=="Witch Doctor":
    PickedBuild=print(random.choice(WDBuild))
    print(PickedBuild)

input("press something to close")
```

Comment: `picked=print(random.choice(Classes))` probably isn't doing what you think it's doing. You didn't notice that `print(picked)` isn't doing anything?

Comment: I didn't notice that...like I said I'm still really new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was where you were trying to set the return of a print to a variable, which you can't do

```
picked=print(random.choice(Classes))
```

Because it gives a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

This is what you wanted to do:

```
picked = random.choice(Classes)
print(picked)
```

The code below should work now

```
import random

Classes=["Demon Hunter","Monk","Crusader","Barbarian","Necromancer","Wizard","Witch Doctor"]

DHBuild=["Impale","Multishot","Natalya's"]
MBuild=["Wave of Light","Uliana's EP","Sunwuko LTK",]
CBuild=["Condemn","Blessed Shield","Sweep Attack"]
BRBuild=["Hammer of the Ancients","WhirlWind","LeapQuake"]
NECROBuild=["Pestilance","Rathma Mages","Inarius"]
WIZBuild=["Frozen Orb","Lightning Hydra","TalVyrs Archon"]
WDBuild=["Arachyr FireBats","Jade Harvester","Helltooth FireBats"]

picked= random.choice(Classes)

print(picked)

if picked=="Demon Hunter":
    PickedBuild = random.choice(DHBuild)
    print(PickedBuild)

if picked=="Monk":
    PickedBuild= random.choice(MBuild)
    print(PickedBuild)

if picked=="Crusader":
    PickedBuild= random.choice(CBuild)
    print(PickedBuild)

if picked=="Barbarian":
    PickedBuild= random.choice(BRBuild)
    print(PickedBuild)

if picked=="Necromancer":
    PickedBuild= random.choice(NECROBuild)
    print(PickedBuild)

if picked=="Wizard":
    PickedBuild= random.choice(WIZBuild)
    print(PickedBuild)

if picked=="Witch Doctor":
    PickedBuild= random.choice(WDBuild)
    print(PickedBuild)

input("press something to close")
```

Comment: So all that I was doing wrong was printing stuff twice? Either way, thanks.

Comment: @XIIIMortis specifically you were getting an error by setting a variable equal to the return of a print. `picked=print(random.choice(Classes))` This gives an incorrect syntax error when you run it, which will cause your script to crash. If you run your code in the command line/terminal you will be able to see all of the errors and the line numbers they occur on, which is helpful when learning